# Necessary and sufficient condition for $\text{tr}\log(A+iB)+\text{tr}\log(A-iB)$ to be real?

Tags: matrices, logarithms

Assume $A$ and $B$ are square matrices which allow $\log(A+iB)$ and $\log(A-iB)$ to be well defined. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ and $B$ to make the aforementioned trace to be real valued?

**Edit:** A sufficient condition is that $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint and commute, with $A$ being positive definite, since then $A+iB$ is a normal matrix. Hence, if $A+iB$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda_n$, $A-iB$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda_n^*$. Hence the trace expression is
$$\text{tr}\log(A+iB)+\text{tr}\log(A-iB)=\sum_n\log(|\lambda_n|^2)\in\mathbb{R}$$

$A$ being positive definite is to avoid any potential branch cut issues with the logarithm. I am trying to understand whether this is also a necessary condition, or if there are some less restrictive properties of $A$ and $B$ which allow the trace in question to be real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\Vert A+iB - I\Vert <1$ and $\Vert A-iB - I\Vert 
<1$, which is the common condition for the corresponding matrix logarithms to be defined (see Thm 2.8 in Hall, *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*, 2015).  Then, it is the case that (Thm 2.8 in Hall):
$$\exp({\ln (A+iB)}) = A+iB,\qquad \exp({\ln (A-iB)}) = A-iB \tag{1} $$
We will also use that for all matrices $X$ (Thm 2.12 in Hall):
$$\det(\exp(X)) = \exp({\mathrm{tr} X})\tag{2}$$
Finally, we will use that $\det X \det Y =\det XY$ for all matrices $X$ and $Y$. We write $^*$ for complex conjugate and $^\dagger$ for conjugate transpose.

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ implies
\begin{align}
&\exp[{\mathrm{tr} \ln (A+iB) + \mathrm{tr} \ln (A-iB))}] \\
&=\exp[{\mathrm{tr} \ln (A+iB) ]\exp[\mathrm{tr} \ln (A-iB))}] \\
&= \det[\exp({\ln (A+iB)}) ]\det[\exp({\ln (A-iB)) }]\\
&= \det(A+iB)\det (A-iB)\\
&= \det((A+iB)(A-iB))
\end{align}
It is clear that ${\mathrm{tr} \ln (A+iB) + \mathrm{tr} \ln (A-iB))}$ is real *if and only if* $$\det((A+iB)(A-iB))=\det(A^2 +i(BA-AB)+B^2)$$ is real and strictly positive.  Some simple sufficient conditions for this to be the case:

- If $A$ and $B$ are real-valued, then $A+iB=(A-iB)^*$, so $$\det(A-iB)=\det((A+iB)^*)=(\det(A+iB))^*$$
  and therefore $\det(A+iB)\det(A-iB)=\vert \det(A+iB)\vert^2$.
- If $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint, then $A^\dagger=A$ and $(iB)^\dagger=-iB$ (since $iB$ is skew-adjoint), so
  $$\det(A-iB)=\det(A^\dagger+(iB)^\dagger)=\det((A+iB)^\dagger)=(\det(A+iB))^*$$
  and therefore $\det(A+iB)\det(A-iB)=\vert \det(A+iB)\vert^2$.

Example where $B$ is neither real nor self-adjoint, and the product of determinants is not positive: consider the 1-by-1 matrices $A=1/2$ and $B=i$. Then, $\det(1/2-1)\det(1/2+1)=-3/4$.

Comment: Is the relationship $\log\det X = \text{tr}\log X$ valid for any matrix $X$?

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_determinant_of_the_matrix_exponential .

Comment: I guess what I am wondering is, can we always make the extra step and write $\log\det(A^2 +i(BA-AB)+B^2)=\text{tr}\log(A^2+i(BA-AB)+B^2)$? It doesn't seem like you can for any choice of $A$ and $B$, considering we could have equally arrived at $A^2 +i(AB-BA)+B^2$ inside the argument.

Comment: When you say "This is satisfied when $A$ and $B$ commute and are self-adjoint..." do you mean it is only satisfied when these are true @Artemy

Comment: @fewfew4 I have edited my answer to make this more explicit and the assumptions clearer.  And yes, the determinant of $(A+iB)(A-iB)$ and $(A-iB)(A+iB)$ is the same.

Comment: @fewfew4 I have further modified my answer. Actually the sufficient conditions are quite general: the result holds if $A$ and $B$ are both real-valued, as well as if they are both self-adjoint (in either case, they don't need to commute).